# Let $N$ be a submodule of $R$-module $M$, $M/N$ is free $R$-module. Prove that $N$ is direct summand of $M$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $N$ be a submodule of $R$-module $M$, $M/N$ is free $R$-module.
>   Prove that $N$ is direct summand of $M$.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The following exact sequence splits (as $M/N $ is free), so $N$ is a direct summand of $M$,

$0\rightarrow N\rightarrow M\rightarrow M/N\rightarrow 0$

Comment: Very nice hint, thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome @user109584

Answer (score 1):

See any text-book, e.g., N.Bourbaki, Algebra, Chapt.II, Sec.11, Prop.21.

Comment: You are welcome.